# Trouble creating folder in SharePoint Online (PnP module)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am trying to use PowerShell to create a new folder in a Teams document library, using the PnP Sharepoint Online module.

I can authenticate to the site in both PowerShell and in a browser. Then I run this code:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$result = Add-PnPFolder -Folder "/sites/SalesDemo/Shared Documents/General/Acme Corp" -Name "testfolder" -Connection (Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com' -Credentials $cred)
```

The result looks fine, showing the name, type, items/size, and last modified time, but when I view the site in SharePoint or in Teams, I do not see "testfolder". However, "testfolder" is returned when I run:

```
Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl "/sites/SalesDemo/Shared Documents/General/Acme Corp" -ItemType Folder -Connection (Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com' -Credentials $cred)
```

Unfortunately, there are other folders in "Acme Corp" that are not returned.

Where is my "testfolder" being created?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

As discussed, when using Connect-PnPOnline, the url parameter should be the same as the site url where the library hosted, if it's hosting in specific site collection, the url should be:

https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SalesDemo

The testfolder should be located at the relative url:

/sites/SalesDemo/Shared Documents/General/Acme Corp

"Acnm Corp" should be a subfolder within /Shared Documents/General folder, the test folder should be there:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it _should_ be there, but I don't see it. I updated my original post to include some screenshots.

Comment: I also checked the "Files" tab in Teams and the folder is not there either.

Comment: Very strange issue, can you replace with another library sub follder url and check to see if the newly created folder can be accessed ?

Comment: Turns out that the issue was the site connection. I was using `(Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com' -Credentials $cred)` when I should have been using `(Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SalesDemo' -Credentials $cred)`. In retrospect, this seems quite obvious.

Comment: Yes, when using Connect-PnPOnline, the url parameter should be the same as the site url where the library hosted. As in original question, this command weren't listed, so I assume you are using the right url :). Now I will edit in my reply to involve this point so that it will also help others.